# add square brackets around timestamp in OneNote 2010

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

Is it possible to add a timestamp (or one of the other date/time stamps) with square brackets automatically put around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use AutoHotKey to create a shortcut to type
[SHIFT+ALT+T] (or F or D) and that should work fine.